# What is the difference between 20$ and $20?

Tags: symbols

I am seeing both 20$ and $20 usages. (20 is nonessential to this question.)

What is the difference between them?

Comment: The $ is usually put before the number to discourage forging. It's much harder to change $20 to $320 than with changing 20$ to 320$.

Comment: @John Smith: that explanation doesn't fly, as it is extremely easy to change $20 to $200, but you can't change 20$ to 200$. Besides, if your theory were true, that would mean that accountants from many other countries are somehow stupider than their American and British colleagues.

Comment: @RegDwight There is usually a period at the other end so my explanation still holds.

Comment: It would actually be pretty useful in discouraging forging of numbers if we padded all the whole number with dollar signs... $362$ !

Comment: @sova, In banking documents the digits are duplicated by spelled writing and blank spaces are striken out from any side - in the left, in the right, in the top and and in the bottom. I would like to restrict the question by electronic (Email, internet forum posts) texts

Comment: I understood that the $ placement is language dependent as it was demonstrated in answers about different usage of euro sign in France and $ in French (Canada) vs. English(Canada). Though, the main question was rather about denoting foreign currency, using the same $, in English texts

Comment: @RegDwight you can not only change *$20* to *$200* but also *20$* to *220$* which is better because you even get more money ;). SO I don't think fraud prevention is a valid reason, if it was, we should write *$20$*, I think it's more of a custom, a preferred usage. Although it makes more sense to me to write any units *after* the number as in 20$, the same way you read it, *twenty dollars*, not *dollars twenty*.

Comment: @RegDwight How about $20.00? :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the English language as such, the dollar symbol and its meaning is not in discussion, but the question is focussed on its physical position.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is the convention of some countries to put their currency symbol before the number, while others put it after the number.

At least one country has put it in the middle.

So you could assume, in the absence of any context, that the 20$ is a different currency to $20.

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, which country puts its currency symbol in the middle of numbers? :-)

Comment: @Tragicomic "...before they were abolished, the signs for the Portuguese escudo and the French franc were placed in the decimal position (i.e., 50$00 or 12₣34)"  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign

Comment: Is there any actual currency that's commonly written *20$*? I think a better explanation is the inconsistencies mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @JSBangs: An amount of Portuguese escudos without a fractionary part could be written like that: 20$. Fractionary parts were kind of rare (at least during my lifetime), because there was only one coin of a non-integral denomination, 2$50. That was enough to buy... a mint.

Comment: @JSBangs @Ed In French-speaking Canada, the dollar sign is often written after the number. 50$ or 50.00$. In English, it's always before the number.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, I worked as programmer in banks of Portugal and fractional part could not be ommitted at any occasion in any documents. There was hyperinflation in Portugal in the 1970-80s but Portugal still had centavos and even half-centavo in circulation till the introduction of euro.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, writing fractional parts is not the biggest inconvenience. Portuguses (and portuguesas) have 6-8 names which they have to write out in all documents without omissions, each time, for example when they sign papers and most papers require repeating the complete name many times

Comment: @vgv8: As a Portuguese myself, I'll have to correct you there. There was no such thing as half-centavos for more than ten years before the introduction of the euro. Like I said before the only non-integral coin was 2$50. Most Portuguese have one or two given names and two family names; the law forbids more than two given names and more than four surnames. So, Portuguese have 2-6 names, not 6-8.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, I am sorry to forget some details. Do I remember incorrectly about 6 names in written used by Portugueses? Could you remind the term of portuguese currency unit/coin less than centavo (100 "terms" = 1 centavo)? I desperately cannot recall and find it by googling

Comment: @vgv8: you're confusing the fraction with the unit. The currency was called the [escudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portuguese_escudo) (1 escudo = 1$00), and 1/100 of a escudo was called a centavo (1 centavo = 0$01).

Comment: Just now I listening [a song-tribute to Antoine Marie Jean-Baptiste Roger de Saint-Exupéry, the author of little Prince"](http://twitter.com/#!/vgv8/status/36953277891493888) I noticed the same with French names

Comment: @Ed Guiness: that is still valid in France, with the Euro. You would write 5€30 for instance.

Comment: This is not about countries. It's about languages. In English, you put the dollar sign before the amount. $10 and the sign for other currencies as well. So, you write $10 but you SAY: ten dollars, if reading it.

Answer (score 67):

In English, the dollar sign is placed before the amount, so the correct order is *$20*, as others have noted.

However, when you see people using *20$*, it's likely they're being influenced by a few different things:

1. Many other countries (and the Canadian province  of Quebec) put the currency symbol after the amount
2. In spoken English the word *dollars* follows the amount, e.g. *twenty dollars*
3. The sign for *cents* is placed after the amount: *25¢*

Because of these inconsistencies, writing *20$* is a very common mistake. I've been known to do it myself.

Comment: +1 for mentioning in #3 that the currency mark comes before the amount and the coinage mark comes after the amount.

Comment: What really irks me is when people write things like "$20 dollars".

Comment: Really I never use either $20 or 20$ but 20 USD. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @Hellion, what always amuses *me* are the signs that say ".99¢". (When my 7th grade algebra teacher saw something like this, she would give the cashier a penny and say "keep the change".)

Comment: @Martha Nice :), but cashier is not guilty, it is marketers who wrote,  the dot is not seen by me, it was "[dot]99¢"

Comment: @Marthaª: And when you start telling people your internet service costs 0.002 ¢/kB, it gets messy.

Answer (score 21):

In American English, the currency symbol is placed before the amount; the same is true for British English.
It is *$20*, not *20$*.

Comment: Not true. when in American English you write the euro (like 20€ ) you put it on the end.

Comment: @ja72: [citation needed].  As an American, I've always seen and written the Euro's currency symbol before the amount -- €20.  The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro) also uses the symbol-first style.  In fact, "20€" looks strange and incorrect to me.

Comment: @josh3736, you seem to me more like Euro-American than American :)

Comment: @ja72, @josh3736: There is no standard regarding euro sign placement; it varies by language and it's entirely conventional. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_sign#Usage

Comment: @CesarGon: [You're absolutely correct.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_issues_concerning_the_euro#Summary)  But in the context of *American English* -- which is what we're talking about here -- the convention is definitely symbol-first.

Comment: @josh3736: I don't dispute that. As I said, each language applies its own convention.

Comment: I do a "booze-cruise" across the Channel to France a few times a year, and it seems to me the French usually put the currency symbol *after* the amount. But I find it interesting that [on their homepage](http://www.pidou.com/modulosite2/wine-calais.htm), Pidou Supermarkets show their in-store "exchange rate" as **£1.00 = 1.15€** right next to a rolling display showing, for example, **6 bottles for €11.50**

Answer (score 9):

The location of the currency depends on the language in which it appears.

For [instance](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-370303.htm#position), English texts should use "€ 20" while French ones should use "20 €".

Comment: +1 Thanks, this is helpful though € does not cause any confusion as the $ symbol does

Comment: Unfortunately there is no agreed/adopted English (France), at least, now. 20 € is adopted for French (France). It is interesting to note that English (Canada) uses $20 and French(Canada) 20$. One can see currency format in Operating system Regional and Language Options

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned in passing, those are not the only two possibilities. In France at least, you sometimes find prices written as **19€95**, as an alternative to **19,95€** (and yes, the decimal separator there is the comma).

Comment: In France they write it that way because they are writing French and not English. It's the language that is important here, not the currency.

Comment: @long-pseudonym: I most certainly agree; I was only pointing out that some languages have a third alternative

Comment: Btw, it's enough to type the first three characters to address someone. So @Mr. would presumably work.

Answer (score 5):

20$ is French-Canadian and $20 is English-Canadian/American.

[French Canadian Dollar in Wiki](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_canadien)

Comment: The Office for Quebec's French language have a page on that : http://www.granddictionnaire.com/BTML/FRA/r_Motclef/index800_1.asp

Comment: +1 thanks, one more useful answer. I already did not expect any new influx. You'd better add by editing

Comment: This is very good answer. I do not like to re-mark my answers but I shall think once more tomorrow morning, thanks again

Comment: Unfortunately I could not grasp whether this convention is hooked to French language or to French Canadian Dollar?

Comment: My guest is : it's French. And the only French speaking in the world that use the '$' sign for their currency is the Québécois (which I am :D)

Comment: @ Martha : Thanks for the correction, I'm not a perfect English writer ;)

Answer (score 2):

For dollars, the correct way is $20.  When I see 20$ it means the writer was thinking "twenty dollars" (not "dollars twenty") and accordingly it is natural to type 20$ and if the writer is feeling lazy she will not backspace to correct it.  Laziness is more common in casual contexts.

Comment: +1 Thanks. Might be  it was obvious for English speaking people but not for me.

Comment: I'd add that people who speak a language where the currency symbol goes after the amount do that in English too because they're not aware it's different and it's not because of laziness. ;)

Answer (score 1):

$20 is conventional, but to throw a wrench in the whole thing: if it is casual correspondence, either way is OK.

Comment: Do you mean that $20 and 20$ are casual writing? I would expect 20 USD be used in formal documents and even in casual correspondence in order to avoid ambiguity. It is confusing to me when an Argentian writes in English-written text the  $20 or the 20$. Is it Argentian Peso or USD?

Comment: Casual, formal, email, printed, doesn't matter: if the language is English, $20 is the **only** correct way to use the dollar sign. 20$ is **always** incorrect in English.

Comment: And who asked about dollar sign? $ is the currency sign, denoting a multitude of different currencies. It doesn't tell anything which one. BTW, the [dollar sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_sign), initially called peso sign, does not identify currency either

Comment: @vgv8, re "And who asked about the dollar sign?": You did. The name of the **$** symbol is "dollar sign". It is not a generic currency symbol. (There is a generic currency symbol defined, but I've never seen it used: **¤**.) Yes, there are multiple currencies that use the dollar sign, but that's irrelevant to English usage.

Comment: "$20" is, in fact, not english at all.

Answer (score 1):

Why all the overcomplication? The difference is that, **in English**, $20 is the *correct* way to use the dollar sign, while 20$ is an *incorrect* way to use the dollar sign. That's all there is to it.

Other languages and currencies are irrelevant to the question. Heck, how the *cent* sign is used is irrelevant to the question, even though it is arguably the same currency and definitely the same language.

Comment: Does English forbid using non-dollar currencies? ["The dollar sign ($), originally called the peso sign, is a symbol primarily used to indicate the various peso and dollar units of currency around the world"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_sign). There is nothing in its definition stipulating its relative position as well as it is only for dollar.  Also, it is not clear that $ denotes dollar but not some other non-dollar [currency  sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign)

Comment: It is not me who downvoted you but, as afterthought, I just looked into Currency format in in the Windows Control Panel--> Regional and Language Options for Spanish(Mexico):  $123,456,789.00 . Now, If a Mexican writes $20 in English text, how do you know which currency he means? And

Comment: Portguese escudo, before euro adoption, used "dollar sign" and it was put neither at the left nor at the right.

Comment: Poor, lousy and trolling answer.

Comment: I am truly puzzled by all the downvotes. @vgv8: since the question is about the $ sign (which is called the "dollar sign" in common parlance), I fail to see what relevance other currencies have. Also, your remark about Portuguese usage makes no sense: if it "was put neither at the left nor at the right", what location does that leave? Behind my ear on the little shelf, as my mother likes to say? @Petruza, "poor" and "lousy" mean the same thing, so it's redundant to list both adjectives; and I'm not trolling, I'm just stating facts.

Comment: @Martha: other currencies are relevant because the $ sign is used for [many other currencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar_sign)!  As other answers point out, 20$ is correct in e.g. French-speaking Canada ([an example](http://www.microbytes.com/computer/ordinateur/index.php?language=fr)).  Insofar as the OP is probably asking about US usage, though, I’d agree with your answer.

Answer (score -3):

I think that part of putting the symbol preceding the number is to help differentiate between dollars and cents. The dollar symbol always precedes, while the cent symbol always follows. If both were to followed, this could potentially become confusing, as a roughly written S with a vertical strike could be mistaken for a c with a vertical strike.

Comment: This line of reasoning is from the realm of wild speculation, and worse still, I'm not even following it. Numbers themselves can be easily mistaken for other numbers, and often are. Yet nothing has been done about *that*. Besides, again, you suggest that accountants from other countries are dumber or more careless than their American and British colleagues.