# Should it be 10 US$ or US$ 10?

Tags: word-choice, abbreviations, money

Which is correct to use in a sentence, 10 US$ or US$ 10. Perhaps USD should be used instead or even something else?

Comment: @RegDwight: my first thought too was that this is a duplicate of [What is the difference between 20$ and $20?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11326/what-is-the-difference-between-20-and-20), but on a second reading, I don’t think it is.  This question is about what to do when the currency is being disambiguated more specifically as US$ — which quite conceivably could be different.

Comment: @PLL: Fair enough. Let's have some answers, then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're going to use a symbol rather than spell out the currency's name, you should always put the currency symbol directly to the left of the digits:  "$10" and never "10 $".

As for the placement of the country indicator, it's generally before the symbol/amount string: 
"US $10", although I have seen "$10 US" in magazines as well, so (as long as you're consistent) I wouldn't worry too much.

If you choose "USD", it seems to be your choice whether to put it to the left or the right: "USD 10" or "10 USD".

However, if you're talking about larger amounts - millions, billions, trillions - the rules are a bit more strict:
"US $10 billion", "USD 10 billion"

In newspaper and magazine usage recently, it's almost always simply "$" or "dollar", with no national specifier - I looked at today's Wall Street Journal, New York Times, Times of London, Le Monde, Le Figaro, and Der Spiegel - none of them specify the country when referring to dollar amounts (although the French refuse to use a symbol or abbreviation.)

Answer (score 8):

If you are trying to make it clear that these are United States dollars (rather than the mighty Canadian version)

"$10 US" or in a more formal economics text possibly, "10 USD"

Comment: In Argentina (and possibly other Latin American countries) they write 10 U$

Comment: @snumpy, but this is English language and usage

Comment: does that mean that a reference in a comment to how something is represented in a non-English speaking environment is pretentious and uncalled for?

Comment: @snumpy - No, but i'm assuming that they write US$ because in spanish that word order makes more sense. So it's a function of spanish language and usage not about the US currency.

Comment: in Spanish, the word order of *Dólares Estadounidenses* would not lend toward US$ but something closer to $US, DE, $E, or $EEUU (which is the Latin American equivalent of USA). I just thought it interesting that they instead replace the *S* of *US* with a dollar symbol.

Comment: The ISO standard for currency codes apparently doesn't dictate the formatting/style of the designator (USD 10 or 10 USD). EU apparently suggests [currency code+ hard space + number: USD 10; EUR 35). Cite: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Code_position_in_amount_formatting

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to either use the appropriate sigil (e.g. $) or the ISO currency code (e.g. USD) as a prefix, rather than mixing them. Alternatively, use the sigil, and follow the quantity with a country specifier (e.g. $10 US, $14 CA or $14 Canadian).

Answer (score 1):

I work in a law office and this is how we are doing it now (lately) (US)$10,000.00!