# Why do we use a leading dollar sign?

Tags: history, symbols, measuring-units

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between 20$ and $20?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11326/what-is-the-difference-between-20-and-20)
>   [Why is the unit of measure placed before the value for currencies? Are there other measures where the unit precedes value?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34013/why-is-the-unit-of-measure-placed-before-the-value-for-currencies-are-there-othe)

We express fifty dollars, not as "50$", but rather as "$50".  Other units are expressed with a trailing symbol (20¢, 10m, 5kWh, 6oz).  Why are dollars treated specially; what's the history behind this?